# Passing all of the state from Container to Presenter in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native and trying to use presenter, container pattern.
And I am facing issue how to pass all of the state from Container to Presenter.

For example.

```js
// PhoneLoginContainer.js

class PhoneLoginContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    phoneNumber: {
      value: "",
      valid: null
    },
    name: {
      value: "",
      valid: null
    },
    loading: false
  };

  render() {
    const { phoneNumber, name, loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <PhoneLoginPresenter
        phoneNumber={phoneNumber}
        name={name}
        loading={loading}
        onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

```js
// PhoneLoginPresenter.js

const PhoneLoginPresenter = (
  name,
  phoneNumber,
  loading,
  onInputChange
) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Enter your mobile number</Text>
      </View>
      <Input
        name="Phone Number"
        placeholder="01082970157"
        onChangeText={value => onInputChange("phoneNumber", value)}
        keyboardType="phone-pad"
        value={phoneNumber.value}
        maxLength={11}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

If I do it like this, I cannot access to `name.value, name.valid` or `phoneNumber.value, phoneNumber.valid`.

Is there any way to pass all the nested state to Presenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass all the `state` from the Father Component, you only need to do the following:

```
// PhoneLoginContainer.js

class PhoneLoginContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    phoneNumber: {
      value: "",
      valid: null
    },
    name: {
      value: "",
      valid: null
    },
    loading: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <PhoneLoginPresenter
        ...this.state
        onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This way, you'll destructure the current state and pass all it's items as props for the `<PhoneLogicPresenter />` (If you want to know more about `destructuring` go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment)).

Answer (score 1):

You could deconstruct your state within the component's props :

```
  <PhoneLoginPresenter
    ...this.state
    onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
  />
```